# Magento: Accessing catalog and cart rule data

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I'm building an extension that exports completed order information into a CSV file. I've been able to successfully access order and item information for the export but I'm having a problem accessing promotion data.

I'm looking to include the promotion data (catalog and cart rules) that are applied to that order in the export. Specifically I am trying to access the rule ids, names, descriptions, codes and applied dollar amount for a list of specific orders.

**How would I access the promotion data in my extension?**

If it helps, here is how I am currently accessing order/item data in my extension (qualifying by date frame):

```
$rows = array(); // array to hold data that will be exported to CSV
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$orders = $read->query("SELECT entity_id FROM sales_flat_order WHERE created_at >= '$from' AND created_at < '$today'");
while ($row = $orders->fetch()) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($row['entity_id']);
    $order_items = $read->query("SELECT item_id FROM sales_flat_order_item WHERE order_id={$order->getId()}");
    while ($item_row = $order_items->fetch()) {
       $item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load($item_row['item_id']);
       $rows[] = array(
         $order->getRealOrderId(),
         $order->getCreatedAt(),
         $item->getSky(),
         $item->getQtyOrdered(),
         ..... );
   ); // end item loop
); // end order loop
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide,

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question has been answered on another question in the past. You can find the link to the original question and answer here [Magento - get price rules from order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649695/magento-get-price-rules-from-order)

From that answer though..

```
//The order I want to check
$order_id = 859;

//Get the list of items for your order
$items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
->getCollection()
->addFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$order_id));

//loop through each item
foreach($items as $item){

    //if the item has not had a rule applied to it skip it
    if($item->getAppliedRuleIds() == '')continue;

    /*
    * I cant remember in the database they might be comma separated or space if multiple rules were applied
    * the getAppliedRuleIds() function is the one you want
    */
    foreach(explode(",",$item->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleID){        

        //Load the rule object
        $rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleID);

        // Throw out some information like the rule name what product it was applied to

        echo "<p>".$item->getSku()." had rule ".$rule->getName()."(".$item->getAppliedRuleIds().") applied </p>";
    }

}
```